How do I prevent KeyRelease events for keys triggering the command of a menu item in tkinter?
In an application that has a menu, a widget is bound to the <KeyRelease> event.
If a menu-item is triggered using the keyboard, after the command of the menu-item in addition the <KeyRelease> event is fired and that same key trigger in addition the action bound to the <KeyRelease> event of the widget. How can I prevent that and make sure that when a menu is open, no events get fired or caught?
Minimal example:
import tkinter as tk


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None)  # , padx=2, pady=2)

        self.menu_main = tk.Menu(self)
        self.menu_file = tk.Menu(self.menu_main)
        self.menu_main.add_cascade(label="Test", underline=0, menu=self.menu_file)
        self.menu_file.add_command(label="Key", underline=0, command=self.command)
        self.config(menu=self.menu_main)

        self.bind("<KeyPress>", self.on_key_press)
        self.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.on_key_release)

    def command(self):
        print("command executed")

    def on_key_press(self, event):
        print(f"handle_keypress({event=}), state:{int(event.state)}")

    def on_key_release(self, event):
        print(f"handle_keyrelease({event=}), state:{int(event.state)}")


main = Main()
main.mainloop()

upon pressing the sequence <Alt+T>,k the following is printed:
handle_keypress(event=<KeyPress event keysym=Alt_L keycode=64 x=515 y=-140>), state:0
handle_keypress(event=<KeyPress event state=Mod1 keysym=t keycode=28 char='t' x=515 y=-140>), state:8
command executed
handle_keyrelease(event=<KeyRelease event keysym=k keycode=45 x=491 y=-128>), state:0

I do want to prevent the handle_keyrelease for keysym=k to happen. It was the trigger for the command (menu-item) and shall not trigger further actions.
A few changes to command were tried already but I could not find a clean solution:
    def command(self):
        # Unbinding here is fine, but when to re-add the binding?
        self.unbind("<KeyRelease>")
        print("command executed")

        # If the binding is added immediately, then it is there already when
        # the <KeyRelease> event happens.
        # self.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.on_key_release

        # Waiting for the event loop does not help, the binding still is installed
        # before the event. Also self.update() does not do the trick.
        # self.update_idletasks()
        # self.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.on_key_release)

        # Adding the binding with a delay does work, but this is nasty:
        self.after(100, lambda: self.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.on_key_release))

Is there a better way than using a delay to achieve this?

I may be misunderstanding what you're after, but if all you want is to be able to access the menu item with the keyboard via Alt-t followed by k, you can do that without binding anything to '<KeyPress>' or '<KeyRelease>'.

Thanks for the hint. No, that is not what I am after.  and  are designed for different actions. Opening / accessing menu is done with tkinter internal mechanism - the underlined letter.

What is your goal with the key bindings?

Performing autocompletion in a combo box. E.g.: https://ttkwidgets.readthedocs.io/en/sphinx_doc/_modules/ttkwidgets/autocomplete/autocompletecombobox.html - the completion is triggered by triggering a menu entry via keyboard (essentially Alt+t followed by any letter triggers autocompletion).

If you're triggering a Menu item, why not just put the autocomplete routine(s) in the menu callback?

Not sure if i understand what you mean. I am typing in the combobox to enter text. Typing letters in the combobox triggers autocompletion (based on the contents of the widget/the letter that is typed). This is done by the  handlers of the respective combobox. In between I want to trigger an action via the menu, then i want to continue typing in the combobox. The menu action does influence the autocompletion because it causes another  event that is caught by the combobox. This is what I am attempting to prevent.

Why don't you bind the events to the combobox instead of root if you just want the key bindings work on the autocompletion in the combobox?

In the real world they are bound to the combobox. This is a minimal example to illustrate the situation. It makes no difference whether they are bound root or the combobox,. The combobox has the focus, then the menu (shortly) has the focus (while command is executed), then the combobox gets back the focus and only then the event happens. This means the combobox sees it.


I do want to prevent the handle_keyrelease for keysym=k to happen. It was the trigger for the command (menu-item) and shall not trigger further actions.

If you want your own callback to prevent the built-in handler for an event to be called, your callback needs to return the literal string "break".
def on_key_press(self, event):
    if event.keysym == "k":
        return "break"


def on_key_release(self, event):
    if event.keysym == "k":
        return "break"

I'm not entirely sure if this will solve your problem, though, since menus don't use the built-in event handling on some platforms -- tkinter essentially gives control to the OS while the menu is open.

Thanks for the idea. Don't know if i understand it correctly - you suggest to return "break" from the event-handler that is triggering the menu, correct? Indeed, afaict this is handled by tkinter internally and I don't think that is a possibility.

@bonsige: tkinter is designed specifically for your bound functions to use the return string "break" to prevent the default bound function from executing. The code in this answer works in that it prevents any default action when you press the "k" character. It's not exactly what you want, but the point is to illustrate how custom functions can prevent default behavior.


Is there a better way than using a delay to achieve this?

I can only suggest an also a little nasty, but not as nasty as a delay, workaround:
    def __init__(self):
        …
        self.pressed = set()

    …

    def on_key_press(self, event):
        …
        self.pressed |= {event.char}

    def on_key_release(self, event):
        if event.char not in self.pressed: return
        self.pressed -= {event.char}
        …

